# How can i remove multiple parts of audio in 1 command with Ffmpeg?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video

Im trying to cut multiple parts of audio with ffmpeg, i was able to find a working result (for video ) for a single filter :
 `ffmpeg -i input.avi -vf "select='1-between(t,20,25)', setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB" -af "aselect='1-between(t,20,25)', asetpts=N/SR/TB" output.avi`

How can i adapt this code for a multiple filters? For example if i want to remove fragments from 10to20, 50to60 etc.

Thank you

Comment: Are you dealing with a video file as input, or is this only audio? In case of the latter, you could look into [sox](https://sox.sourceforge.net/) and its [trim](https://sox.sourceforge.net/sox.html#trim) parameter.

Answer (score 3):

You can combine several `between` intervals, as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50594412/cut-multiple-parts-of-a-video-with-ffmpeg . Just copying the command from this link:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 \
       -vf "select='between(t,4,6.5)+between(t,17,26)+between(t,74,91)',
            setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB" \
       -af "aselect='between(t,4,6.5)+between(t,17,26)+between(t,74,91)',
            asetpts=N/SR/TB" out.mp4
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reach the result i want with this command : `ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -af "aselect='not(between(t,10,16)+between(t,20,50))'" output.mp3`

Answer (score 0):

Copying the video to a new file and deleting the audio while doing so is the quickest and easiest technique to remove or delete audio. This method is straightforward because you don't have to re-encode the movie while you're at it. The command line to accomplish this is provided here.
ffmpeg.exe -i videoWithAudio.mp4 -c:v copy -an videoWithoutAudio.mp4
-c:v copy copies the video track into videoWithoutAudio.mp4
-an tell FFmpeg to not copy the audio

Comment: If I read the question correctly the OP is not looking to remove all audio, nor do they have a video file they start with. They have an audio file from which they want to delete multiple sections in one command. Would you know how to do that?

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke it looks like the file the OP is dealing with has audio+video. That said, the above answer is definitely not an answer to the question.